# How to rearrange data format using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have some data in the format:

```
{ regionalGames1: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
  regionalGames2: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  regionalGames3: [ 3, 5, 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

How could I use lodash to rearrange this data to:

```
{
  1: [regionalGames1],
  2: [regionalGames1, regionalGames2],
  3: [regionalGames1, regionalGames2, regionalGames3],
  4: [regionalGames1, regionalGames2, regionalGames3],
  ...
}
```

and so on?

I'm looking at `_.groupBy` and also `_.keyBy` but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and two `forEach()` loop

```js
var obj = {
  regionalGames1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  regionalGames2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  regionalGames3: [3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
}

var result = {}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e) {
  obj[e].forEach(function(a) {
    (!result[a]) ? result[a] = [e] : result[a].push(e);
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: How could I have it so it displays for all the numbers from 1-7 ?

Comment: Just edited my answer. You can see I write 'and so on'. I'd like to, for each unique value of a regionalGame, display which regionalGames that value is associated with.

Comment: Ohhh i see, you should explain that in question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the 'and so on' wasn't so clear. I've updated it now so it's more clear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is will be a lodash function to do it easily, but a pure javascript answer would work fine for me.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, also `5` is two times in `regionalGames3` so there is two `regionalGames3` in array for `5`, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

**No need to use a third-party library like lodash:**

```js
var data = {
  regionalGames1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  regionalGames2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  regionalGames3: [3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
};

var out = {};

Object.keys(data).map(function(item) {
  data[item].map(function(id) {
    if (!out[id]) out[id] = [];
    out[id].push(item);
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Looks good, there only seems to be one bug, `4` doesn't contain `regionalGames3` and `5` contains `regionalGames3` twice

Comment: Sorry, which is a bug due to my question being improper. This works.